# PHP code only prints out first set of values from submitted HTML form

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've got a web form where people can add in a food item and its respective calories. A user is able to click an 'Add' button and add another item as well to create a list. I am then outputting this submitted data into a HTML table. However, the script will only print out the first index of the array.

**PHP script**

```
function printFoodTable($food, $kcal) {

    $count = 0;
    $items[] = array('food' => $food, 'kcal' => $kcal);

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $item['food'][$count] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $item['kcal'][$count] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $count++;
    }

}
```

**HTML form elements**

```
<input class="item" type="text" name="food[]" placeholder="Item" />
<input class="kcal" type="number" name="kcal[]" placeholder="Kcal" />
```

If I change `$count` to 1 for example. The next pair in the array will be printed. So, I know the array is actually being submitted correctly. In the example below it prints out Banana, 120 but if changed it will be Apple, 140 and so on.

**Example array**

`[0] => "Banana", "120"
 [1] => "Apple", "140"
 [2] => "Grapes", "230"`

**Calling the function on form submission**

```
printFoodTable($_POST['food'], $_POST['kcal']);
```

**WORKING SOLUTION**
Thanks to a brilliant answer. Here is the working code to loop through the submitted values and print them out.

```
function printFoodTable($food, $kcal) {
    foreach($food as $index => $foodItem) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $foodItem . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $kcal[$index] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to do `$items[] =...` as `array( ... );` makes the variable an' array.

Comment: `$items` only ever has one index in it according to your code. It's a local variable to the function.

Comment: Please specify what `$food` and `$kcal` are when used as the parameters to this function. Show all RELEVANT code or we are just guessing

Comment: They are `$_POST` variables from the HTML form, hence the `food[]` and `kcal[]` so it would be `printFoodTable($_POST['food'], $_POST['kcal']);` when called in the system.

Comment: can you please add dump of `$items` and `$_POST` to be more clear?
`print_r($items); print_r($_POST);`

Comment: `foreach ($food as $k => $f) { echo $f; echo $kcal[$k]; }`

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [food] => Array ( [0] => Banana [1] => Apple [2] => Grapes ) [kcal] => Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 140 [2] => 230 ) ) ) ` print out of $items

Comment: You're initialising `$items` like this: `$items = array(array(...));`, which is why your loop is only running once, just change it to `$items = array('food' => $food, 'kcal' => $kcal);`

Comment: @billyonecan that works perfectly! Can you please explain the logic so I may learn as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have currently is because of this line:

`$items[] = array('food' => $food, 'kcal' => $kcal);`

Which will be creating an array within an array (which explains why your loop is only running once). Just change it to:

`$items = array('food' => $food, 'kcal' => $kcal);`

You don't actually need to create the `$items` array at all, just `foreach` over `$food` or `$kcal`, pass the array's index as the `$key`, and use that to get the other array's corresponding value:

```
foreach ($food as $key => $f) {
  echo $f; // contains current 'food'
  echo $kcal[$key]; // contains corresponding 'kcal'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Billy. Not only do I have a working solution but I actually have a through explanation. Cheers buddy!